# What is the type of a "select"?

Tags: plsql

If I have a function that does a SELECT, how do I return this result? What is the type of the result of the select?

And how can I use the returned result afterwards and do things with it (let's say loop and print it)?

Comment: Hint : cursors - or - if it is only one value or so : select into

Comment: I tried learning cursors, refcursors, recordsets but I am confused and trying to take one thing at a time. Trying to start with a simple question : like, I made a select inside a function, how do I return the results ? How do I use the results later (besides LOOPing and using PUT_LINE) ? And further down the line, how do I chain several function that return / receive the "select" results? [I am kind of thinking functional programming style : take set apply operations, return, give to something else, apply operations, return, give to something else (another function); am I wrong to think so?]

Comment: A little vague, but I had same question just lately, and answered it under `Oracle`

Comment: Please read e.g. [Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html) that is a very good resource.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do you mean something like this.

```
DECLARE  
    /* Define the REF CURSOR type. */  
    TYPE curvar_type IS REF CURSOR RETURN table_name%ROWTYPE;  
    /* Reference it in the parameter list. */  
PROCEDURE open_query (curvar_out OUT curvar_type)  
IS  
    local_cur curvar_type;  
BEGIN  
    OPEN local_cur FOR SELECT * FROM table_name;  
    curvar_out := local_cur;  
END;
```

Instead `table_name%ROWTYPE` can be view or explicit cursor name.

Answer (score 1):

### With Oracle

(I have Oracle 10/11, maybe in earlier version its harder?)

It is a `TABLE` of `%ROWTYPE`. You must collect it using `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

e.g.

```
declare
  TYPE t_ iS TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
  v_t t_;
begin
   select * bulk collect into v_t from MY_TABLE where rownum=1 ;
--- then for printing it --- /!\ depends of the data in your table:
   FOR i in 1..v_t.count
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_t(i).MY_COLUMN));
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to extract values from a table and do something with them:

If you want to find just one specific record you can do the following:

```
DECLARE
  l_variable1  table_name.column_name%TYPE;
  l_variable2  table_name.column_name%TYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT column1, column2
    INTO l_variable1, l_variable2
    FROM table_name
   WHERE column_name_id = 138;
END;
```

This only works if one row is returned, otherwise you'll get an exception saying the query returned more than one row.

If you want several records form a table/view and you need to iterate, use cursors.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C_cursor
   IS
        SELECT column1, column2, columnN
          FROM table_name
        --other clauses

   R_cursor_row   C_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN C_cursor;

   LOOP
      FETCH C_cursor 
       INTO R_cursor_row;
       EXIT WHEN C_cursor%NOTFOUND;

      --do what you need for each record
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE C_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: i need to return the results from withing a function.

Comment: Just save the data into a type and return the type, or a table of that type.